# G-keys on Corsair K30 keyboard

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 15.04, keyboard-layout, xfce

I recently purchased a brand spanking new [Corsair K30](http://www.corsair.com/en-us/raptor-k30-gaming-keyboard) keyboard, and excitedly I decide to plug it into my Xubuntu home PC, and it works like a charm. Well, other than two main things which really disappointed me.

- The G-keys and their profiles cannot be configured to do anything, so they are just sitting there being useless.
- (Not so important) The scroll lock key does nothing.

I was wondering if there is anything I could do to allow me to remap the G-keys to do stuff such as opening the Terminal or a web browser.

Until now, I tried the following things:

- Running the Corsair K30 keyboard software through [Wine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine_%28software%29). It launched and everything seems to work, but it does not detect the keyboard as a K30 and as such does not register any of the "not normal" keys I press, such as the brightness, macro profile, and macro record buttons. (The brightness works and changes the keyboard's LED brightness, but the program does not detect it.)
- Using `xbindkeys` and figuring out the key codes of each G-key and other keys. The G-keys are all the same, but the other keys like the macro profile and the macro record have different ones.
- Just going in through a normal program such as `Keyboard > Application Shortcuts` and trying to bind the G-keys over there.

None of that worked obviously, so is there any other way I could get my keyboard's G-keys to work?

Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 15.04 (Vivid Vervet)

Answer (score 3):

This may be on the bleeding edge, but there is [a Linux kernel driver for Corsair Kxx](http://forum.corsair.com/forums/showthread.php?t=149621) that is currently under active development. The base is Corsair K90, but there are [reports for the Corsair K40](http://forum.corsair.com/forums/showthread.php?t=149621#post_message_810832). It might work for the Corsair K30.

A feature worth mentioning is:

> *Remapping G keys so they send proper key codes.*

An alternative is [the K65/K70/K95 RGB Unofficial Driver for Linux and OS X](http://forum.corsair.com/forums/showthread.php?t=133929), but it seems to be for the RGB editions only. [It is on GitHub](https://github.com/ccMSC/ckb), though.

Note: I don't know about the Corsair K30, but for the [Corsair K95 RGB](http://www.corsair.com/se-fi/corsair-gaming-k95-rgb-mechanical-gaming-keyboard-cherry-mx-red) the G-keys do not work because they are not executed in the keyboard itself, but by software in the operating system (only intended to be Windows).

Comment: I'm checking this out, but I've hit a snag, I can't seem to find the `hid-id` for my Corsair Raptor K30 keyboard, and extensive Googling hasn't returned anything useful, is there any way I can find my `hid-id`?