# Corsair K40 keyboard

Tags: drivers, keyboard, keyboard-layout

https://github.com/cvuchener/k90-linux-driver

> hid-generic takes control of the K90 keyboard, you need to unbind it (at least for the interface 0 of the keyboard, it works well with interface 1 and 2).
>
> ```
> sudo tee /sys/bus/hid/drivers/hid-generic/unbind <<< "0003:1B1C:1B02.XXXX"
> ```
>
> Replace `XXXX` with the correct value for the first interface of the keyboard.

I do not understand what I need to put in for the `XXXX`

Comment: Have you seen this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/664921/g-keys-on-corsair-k30-keyboard/681222#681222

Answer (score 1):

Before you start make sure you know what you are doing

1. Type the following command `dmesg | grep Corsair`
2. You should see something similar to the picture below

   [image: screenshot]
3. The number you are looking for is the one in the location of the circle

   [image: number]